# AWS System Design on Preconfigured EC2s

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS workflow which is as follows: 
API call -> Lambda Function (Paramiko Remote Connect) -> EC2 -> output

Basically, I have an API call, which triggers a lambda function. Within the lambda function, I remote connect to a preconfigured EC2 instance using Python Paramiko, run some commands on the ec2 instance, and then return the output. I have two main concerns with this design: 1.) latency and 2.) scalability.

**For Latency:**  
When I call the API, it takes 8-9 seconds to run, but if I were to run the job directly on the EC2 instance, it would take 1-2 seconds. Do the `ssh_client.connect()` and `ssh_client.exec_command()` cause significantly increased runtime? Also, I am implementing this on a t2-micro ubuntu 18.04 free-tier EC2 instance. Would using the paid versions cause a difference in runtime?

**For Scalability:**  
I am sure AWS has a solution for this, but suppose that there are several simultaneous API calls. I am sure that I can't have only 1 available EC2 instance to run the job. Should I have multiple EC2 instances preconfigured and use a load-balancer? What AWS features can I use to scale this system?

If anything is unclear, please ask and I will elaborate.

Comment: Why do you need a lambda here at all? Can't you just write an API service that rums directly on your EC2 instance? Then you can create an Auto Scaling Group, put a Load Balancer in front of that and define some scaling policies for the ASG, and off you go.

Comment: `@kenny_k` Doesn't the AWS API gateway require you to invoke a lambda function? I am not sure how to create an API without Lambda. Can you refer me to some documentation for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using Paramiko, the more "cloud-friendly" method of running commands on an EC2 instance would be to use [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html), which **uses an agent to run commands on instance**. It can even run commands on multiple instances and also on-premises computers that have the agent installed.

Another design choice is to **push a "job" message to an Amazon SQS queue**. The worker instances can **poll the SQS queue asking for work**. When they receive a message, they can perform the work. This is more of an asynchronous model because the main system does not 'wait' for job to finish, so it needs a return path to provide the results (eg another SQS queue). However, it is highly scalable and more resilient, with no load balancer required. This is a common design pattern.

Comment: I like the idea of an SQS queue. How can I configure an SQS queue to function as an API? Basically, when the client creates a job (through an API call), I need to send the job to the queue and wait for it to finish, and then send the output back to the client? Can you refer me to some documentation which can help me solve this?

Comment: If the job takes some time to execute, it is best done _asynchronously_. That is, rather than "sending the output back to the client", the client should periodically check for the results. However, if the job runs fast enough, it could be provided back in response to the request. For example, when you pay by credit card on a website, the user waits for the credit card transaction to complete (fast), but if something takes several minutes to process, it is best to come back later for the results.

Comment: Some references: [Cloud Queues message patterns - Rackspace Developer Center](https://docs.rackspace.com/support/how-to/cloud-queues-message-patterns/) and [Running Cost-effective queue workers with Amazon SQS and Amazon EC2 Spot Instances | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/running-cost-effective-queue-workers-with-amazon-sqs-and-amazon-ec2-spot-instances/) and [Scaling Microservices with Message Queues to Handle Data Bursts | by Songtham Tung | A Cloud Guru](https://read.acloud.guru/scaling-microservices-with-message-queue-2d389be5b139)